# Magento: Send notification when specific item has been ordered

Tags: magento

We have been using a third party to pack and ship our packages. Therefore we don't see all orders that pass by anymore.

But there are several products that we have to supply manually ourselves, such as a digital gift card. Is there a possibility to have Magento send us an email when a specific SKU has been ordered by a customer? For instance to inform us that we need to create a gift card for a customer?

I don't want to see every order in our emailbox, just with some specific SKU's in it.

Thanks,
Menno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved with a custom module.  Create your module and add an event observer to it's config.xml;

```
<events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <copymein>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>dispatcher/observer</class>
                    <method>ccMyEmail</method>
                </copymein>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
```

Then in Model/Observer.php declare your function;

```
public function ccMyEmai($observer) {

    $order_ids = $observer->getData('order_ids');

    if(isset($order_ids)) {
        foreach ($order_ids as $order_id) :

        $sendToMe = false;
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
            if (isset($order)) {

                 $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
                 foreach ($orderItems as $_item) {

                     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getData('product_id'));
                     if($product->getSku() == ('123' || '234' || '345')) { // Your SKUs
                              $sendToMe = true;
                     }

                 }
             }

         if($sendToMe) {
         $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
         $mail->setToName('Your name');
         $mail->setToEmail('your@email.com');
         $mail->setBody('Order number '.$order->getIncrementId().' has items that need action');
         $mail->setSubject('Order '.$order->getIncrementId().' needs attention');
         $mail->setFromName('Your from name');
         $mail->setFromEmail('your@siteemail.com');
         $mail->setType('text');

                try {
                    $mail->send();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::log($e);
                }
          }



         endforeach;
    }
 }
```

Just a note that it would be more efficient to create a product attribute that isnt visible on the frontend that defines whether a product requires your attention - something along the lines of needs_attention Yes/No, then scan the ordered products for a yes value in that attribute.  Much more manageable than hard coding the SKU's you are looking for ;)

Comment: That seems like a great solution. I haven't created a custom module for Magento before, but hopefully there'll be some good tutorials around. Any thought on how I could change above code when using a custom attribute? That definitely seems like the way to go.

Comment: Really glad it helped.  To use custom attribute, instead of:

if($product->getSku() == ('123' || '234' || '345')) { ///

Do this;
$attrValue = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attr_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

if($attrValue == 'Yes') { ///

Answer (score 1):

You might create a custom module for this functionality. So in the new module, you have to hook Observer event: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action. 
You can do like following as :

```
       <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
               <xxx_checkout_success>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>[Your Module Name]/observer</class>
                   <method>sendEmailToCustomerForSales</method>
               </xxx_checkout_success>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

And, in this sendEmailToCustomerForSales() method, it can send an email to the customer according to a specific SKU.

Please refer this code:

```
public function sendEmailToCustomerForSales($observer) {
    $orderId = (int)current($observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds());
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        if($_product->getSku() == '[Your specific sku]') {
            /*send an email to the customer*/
        }
    }
}
```